# How to security access onprem database from Azure AppService

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-administration

Is there a way to securely access a on-prem Sql Server, from an AppService?

The IT guys are nervious about letting an App Service which needs access to our on-premise database.

I am not a networking guy, and am trying to come up with a solution.

The only thing I have thought of is creating a new database (CDS_API).  The AppService is then given a connection string to this database.  This database would then have access to the primary database (CDS).

If the AppService has only execute permissions to CDS_API, this seems secure to me.  Am I missing something?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Databases aren't given access to other databases, Users and Logins are given access to them. The thought process "*The only thing I have thought of is creating a new database (CDS_API). The AppService is then given a connection string to this database. This database would then have access to the primary database (CDS)."* won't work, as you can't "grant access" to another database to another. Sounds like you should be creating custom APIs in the local environment. Otherwise, you just need to ensure it has the most limited permissions possible and probably create lots of Procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to use an [App Service Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)

> Hybrid Connections can be used to access application resources in any
> network that can make outbound calls to Azure over port 443. **Hybrid
> Connections provides access from your app to a TCP endpoint** and does
> not enable a new way to access your app. As used in App Service, each
> Hybrid Connection correlates to a single TCP host and port
> combination. This enables your apps to access resources on any OS,
> provided it is a TCP endpoint. The Hybrid Connections feature does not
> know or care what the application protocol is, or what you are
> accessing. It simply provides network access.

Alternatively, you can [Integrate your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) which is connected securely to your on-prem networks either with a [Site-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) or over [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/).

Comment: Great, thank you so much Mr. Browne!  I am still digesting the answer, but i am sure it will work out.